# XPages HTTP Internal Error for DojoLibResourceProvider$DojoResource.writeData

Tags: xpages

We are getting multiple exceptions as below on server for XPages applications.
Not sure what causing this exception, and there is no help available on internet.

Kindly help on this. Thank you.

```
CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.io.IOException: HTTP: Internal error: 
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.resources.DojoLibResourceProvider$DojoResource.writeData(DojoLibResourceProvider.java:103)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.resources.AbstractResourceProvider$AbstractResource.write(AbstractResourceProvider.java:153)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesResourceServlet.doGet(FacesResourceServlet.java:110)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesGlobalResourceServlet.service(FacesGlobalResourceServlet.java:83)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.StaticResourcesService.doService(StaticResourcesService.java:63)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTP: Internal error: 
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.servlet.XspCmdHttpServletResponse.write(XspCmdHttpServletResponse.java:860)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.servlet.XspCmdServletOutputStream.write(XspCmdServletOutputStream.java:72)
    at com.ibm.commons.util.io.StreamUtil.copyStream(StreamUtil.java:137)
    at com.ibm.commons.util.io.StreamUtil.copyStream(StreamUtil.java:118)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.resources.DojoLibResourceProvider$DojoResource.writeData(DojoLibResourceProvider.java:97)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: On which domino server version this problem occurs?

Comment: Domino 9.0.1, with FP3.